# How to create conditional for Stripe token based on ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe JS and Flask to create and process a payment form and coupon form on the same page. The coupon form is being submitted via ajax optionally before the payment form is submitted. If a coupon is submitted successfully, I'd like to remove the payment portion of the payment form, and submit the form without Stripe (since I have other data to collect and process server-side).

My coupon code form works as I'd like, and I can conditionally alter the DOM to remove the payment form. But this throws an error since Stripe has already created the token on page load.

But I'm getting tripped up in the order of operations for the JS. Any help would be appreciated!

My JS:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
Stripe.setPublishableKey('some_test_id');

var couponApplied;

var stripeResponseHandler = function(status, response) {
    var $form = $('#purchase_form');

    if (response.error) {
        // Show the errors on the form
        $form.find('.payment-errors').text(response.error.message);
        $form.find('input').prop('disabled', false);
    } else {
        // token contains id, last4, and card type
        var token = response.id;
        // Insert the token into the form so it gets submitted to the server
        $form.append($('<input type="hidden" name="stripeToken">').val(token));
        // and re-submit
        $form.get(0).submit();
    }
};

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#purchase_form').submit(function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);
        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);
        Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
        // Prevent the form from submitting with the default action
        return false;
    });
});

var csrftoken = $('meta[name=csrf-token]').attr('content');
$.ajaxSetup({
    beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
        if (!/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/i.test(settings.type)) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken)
        }
    }
});

$('form#couponcode_form').submit(function() {
    var code = $('input#coupon_code').val();

    $.ajax({
        data: JSON.stringify({
            code: code
        }),
        url: '/code_validate',
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(json) {
            console.log(json);
            $(".ajax_response").text(json.response);
            $(".code_redemption").text(json.price);
            if (json.code_applied === true) {
                var couponApplied = true;
                $("#payment").remove();
            } else {
                var couponApplied = false;
            }
            console.log('Test coupon: ' + couponApplied);

        },
        error: function(request, errorType, errorMessage) {
            console.log(errorType +  ": " + errorMessage);
        }
        });

        return false;
    });

</script>
```

And a portion of my HTML dealing with the forms:

```
<form method='POST' action='/code_validate' id="couponcode_form">
        {{ couponcode_form.csrf_token }}
        {{ couponcode_form.coupon_code.label }} {{ couponcode_form.coupon_code(size=20) }}
        {{ couponcode_form.submit }}
    </form>

    <form action="/buy" method="POST" id="purchase_form">
        {{ form.csrf_token }}
        {{ form.coupon_used }}

        <div class="form_step">
            <h2>1. Your Friend's Name</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="field_grouper" id="recipient">

            <div class="form-group{% if form.recipient_name.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
                {{ form.recipient_name.label }}
                {{ form.recipient_name(class_='form-control', maxlength='250') }}
                <span class="help_text">{{ form.recipient_name.description|safe }}</span> <span class="required">*</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{% if form.recipient_email.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
                    {{ form.recipient_email.label }}
                    {{ form.recipient_email(class_='form-control', maxlength='100') }}
                    <span class="help_text">{{ form.recipient_email.description|safe }}</span>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="form_step">
            <h2>2. Your Friend's Address</h2>
        </div>

        <div class="field_grouper" id="recipient_address">

            <div class="form-group{% if form.shipping_street_address_1.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
                {{ form.shipping_street_address_1.label }}
                {{ form.shipping_street_address_1(class_='form-control', maxlength='250') }}
                <span class="help_text">{{ form.shipping_street_address_1.description|safe }}</span> <span class="required">*</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{% if form.shipping_street_address_2.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
                {{ form.shipping_street_address_2.label }}
                {{ form.shipping_street_address_2(class_='form-control', maxlength='250') }}
                <span class="help_text">{{ form.shipping_street_address_2.description|safe }}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{% if form.shipping_city.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
                {{ form.shipping_city.label }}
                {{ form.shipping_city(class_='form-control', maxlength='250') }}
                <span class="help_text">{{ form.shipping_city.description|safe }}</span> <span class="required">*</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{% if form.shipping_state.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
                {{ form.shipping_state.label }}
                {{ form.shipping_state(class_='form-control', maxlength='2') }}
                <span class="help_text">{{ form.shipping_state.description|safe }}</span> <span class="required">*</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{% if form.shipping_zip.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
                {{ form.shipping_zip.label }}
                {{ form.shipping_zip(class_='form-control', maxlength='9') }}
                <span class="help_text">{{ form.shipping_zip.description|safe }}</span> <span class="required">*</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form_step">
            <h2>3. Add your message</h2>
        </div>
        {% block prefilled_messages %}

        {% endblock %}

        <div class="field_grouper" id="message">
            <h3>Personalized Message:</h3>
            <div class="form-group{% if form.personal_message.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
                {{ form.personal_message.label }}
                {{ form.personal_message(class_='form-control', rows='10') }}
                <span class="help_text">{{ form.personal_message.description|safe }}. You have <b><span id="charsleft"></span></b> characters left.</span><span class="required">*</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="field_grouper" id="purchaser">
            <h3>From:</h3>

            <div class="form-group{% if form.purchaser_name.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
                {{ form.purchaser_name.label }}
                {{ form.purchaser_name(class_='form-control', maxlength='250') }}
                <span class="help_text">{{ form.purchaser_name.description|safe }}</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group{% if form.purchaser_email.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
                {{ form.purchaser_email.label }}
                {{ form.purchaser_email(class_='form-control', maxLength='100') }}
                <span class="help_text">{{ form.purchaser_email.description|safe }}</span> <span class="required">*</span>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form_step">
            <h2>4. Pay</h2>
        </div>

        <span class="code_redemption"></span>

        <div class="field_grouper" id="payment">

            <span class="payment-errors"></span>

            <h3>Credit card:</h3>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" size="20" data-stripe="number">

                <span class="help_text">Card number</span> <span class="required">*</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="cvc">

                <span class="help_text">CVC</span> <span class="required">*</span>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="text" size="2" data-stripe="exp-month">
                <span> / </span>
                <input type="text" size="4" data-stripe="exp-year">

                <span class="help_text">Expiration month and year (MM/YYYY)</span> <span class="required">*</span>
            </div>

        </div>

        <div class="field_grouper" id="submit">
            <button type="submit">Submit Payment</button>
        </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand the flow properly you should be able to move the declaration of variable `couponApplied` to a scope level that is accessible to both form submit handlers.

Then within the purchase submit handler you can bypass the Stripe API if `couponApplied` is true and let the form submit instead of returning false from that submit handler.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    // declare variable with default false
    var couponApplied = false;

    $('#purchase_form').submit(function (e) {

        var $form = $(this);
        // Disable the submit button to prevent repeated clicks
        $form.find('button').prop('disabled', true);

        if (!couponApplied) {
            // only use stripe if no coupon
            Stripe.card.createToken($form, stripeResponseHandler);
        }
        // return true/false by variable will determine if browser submit occurs
        return couponApplied;
    });

    $('form#couponcode_form').submit(function () {
        var code = $('input#coupon_code').val();
        $.ajax({
            //some options not shown for clarity
            success: function (json) {
                // don't use "var" here
                couponApplied = json.code_applied;  
                /* other code */  
            }
        });
    });

});
```

Comment: Works great! Thanks for getting me on the right path!